# How to create a variable in shell script whose name is present in variable?

Tags: sh

Let's say I declare two variables key and value like this in shell script

```
$ key=key1

$ value=value1
```

now I want to create a variable of name key1 and assign it value value1. What I tried is

```
$ export ${key}

$ export ${value}

$ $($key=$value)
```

**output**: key1=value1: command not found

I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Note that `bash` supports `${!key}` to do indirect variable referencing.  If you're not in charge of the contents of the variables, be very careful of the `eval` method.  `key="$(rm -fr / 2>/dev/null & echo Hi)"` is not going to lead to happiness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `eval $key=$value` instead of `$($key=$value)`: The shell substitutes variable values first, and then the `$(...)` substitution. As there is not command with that name the shell shows `command not found` in STDERR. Tell the shell to evaluate the substitution result as a regular shell command again by using `eval`. Later you can export the result with `export $key`. Using the `-x` flag for the shell provides a good insight of what happens:

```
$ key=key1
$ value=value1
$ set -x
$ $key=$value
+ key1=value1
sh: key1=value1: not found [No such file or directory]
$ $($key=$value)
+ key1=value1
sh: key1=value1: not found [No such file or directory]
$ eval $key=$value
+ eval key1=value1
+ key1=value1
$ echo $key1
+ echo value1
value1
$ export $key
+ export key1
```

Also, be careful when dealing with variables this way: Whitespaces in shell variables can have unexpected results in this kind of constructions.